# Unity 4.6 Canvas - How to correctly apply 2D physics effects

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine, physics

Is there a way to universally multiply physics2D calculations on the canvas?

I'm trying to make a set of canvas UI elements with 2D physic properties. The objects contain images and text, but need to respond to gravity, impacts, and overlapping collision boxes with other GUI elements.

I've added 2D RigidBody and boxCollider components to my objects. However, they move very slowly. If given a gravity, they fall slowly. If overlapped, they push each other apart slowly.

I've figured out that this is due to the canvas having a very large scale. My objects are effectively 'very big and very far away'.

- I can't modify the canvas scale. It needs to be huge or I get render artifacts.
- I can't just modify gravity because it doesn't provide a universal fix. Things fall faster, but they don't push apart or spring right.
- I can't modify the timestep because it affects the whole world, not just the canvas.

My canvas objects have widths akin to 80, where unity physics expects widths akin to 1. How can I get them to behave like they have a width of 1?

Is there some universal scaling factor for canvas based physics, or am I simply mis-using the canvas for something it is not intended for?

Comment: Canvas is for UI elements. If you wanna apply physics use 2D Sprites instead.

Comment: The trouble is I want to drag the physics element *on top* of a UI element. If I can control render order with the canvas, I'd be ok.
I might be able to do something with a world space canvas, but that opens up a different can of worms...

Comment: You can render them on top of it.

Comment: Can I interleave them with the canvas elements, so that they are drawn in front of some components and behind others?

Comment: Sure. Canvas has overrideSorting. Or you can use many canvas in diferent sorting layers.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still having this problem, the answer to fixing the movement rates of your scaled-up objects is to scale up your movement forces as well as your gravity.  If you can't get certain elements to work right, use a forcepush that you can set to any strength.